# DataView not Sorting properly after DataTable GroupBy

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, dataview

I am currently getting data from SQL Server and storing in a DataTable. I am applying GroupBy operation on that DataTable in order to display the table in various forms in DataGrid. After making into sub DataTables, I am sorting the DataTable by placing in a DataView. After Sorting   the DataView, I am binding it to a DataGridView. But the problem is that the Rows which are made by GroupBy are not sorting properly

Can I get a Solution for this?

Here is the DataView GroupBy code.

```
DataView view = new DataView(dtfullreport); // Datatable to dataview.
            var drdatedisp = from row in dtfullreport.AsEnumerable()
                             group row by row.Field<string>("Order_Date") into g
                             select new
                             {
                                 Order_Date = g.Key,
                                 totalQnty = g.Sum(a => a.Field<int>("Item_Quantity")),
                                 totalTax = g.Sum(a => float.Parse(a.Field<decimal>("TAXAMT").ToString())),
                                 totalAmt = g.Sum(a => float.Parse(a.Field<decimal>("VALAMT").ToString()))
                             };
            DataTable dtdatedisp = new DataTable();
            dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("Order_Date");
            dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("Item_Quantity");
            dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("TAXAMT");
            dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("VALAMT");
            dtdatedisp.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (var g in drdatedisp)
            {
                DataRow newRow1 = dtdatedisp.NewRow();
                newRow1[0] = g.Order_Date;
                newRow1[1] = g.totalQnty;
                newRow1[2] = String.Format("{0:0.00}", g.totalTax);
                newRow1[3] = String.Format("{0:0.00}", g.totalAmt);
                dtdatedisp.Rows.Add(newRow1);
            }
```

After Grouping the DataView and placing in the DataTable, I'm sorting the DataTable

Here is the Sorting code.
This will be written in GridView Sorting Event.

```
string sortingDirection = string.Empty;
    if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Descending;
        sortingDirection = "Desc";
    }
    else
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
        sortingDirection = "Asc";
    }
            DataView sortedView = new DataView((DataTable)ViewState["dtdatedisp"]);
        sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortingDirection;
        gv_reports_date.DataSource = sortedView; // Gridview datasource and binding
        gv_reports_date.DataBind();
```

I'm sorting based on Order_Date column but after sorting the DataView in Descending Order
but the output is,

Datatable before Grouping

[image]

Default View before sorting. (Sorted according to date in database).

[image]

After sorting in Descending order of Quantity Sold.

[image]

After sorting in Ascending order of Quantity Sold.

[image]

The Rows which are Grouped are not being displayed in correct Sort Order

Comment: Sorry the images in stackoverflow are not being displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is very simple. If you don't provide types for the columns in your sorted DataTable, string is assumed, and the resulting sort is a dictionary sort.

Numbers 10, 6, 30 are going to be ordered as {6, 10, 30} if sorted as integers, but 
{10, 30, 6} if sorted as strings.

Change:

```
DataTable dtdatedisp = new DataTable();
dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("Order_Date");
dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("Item_Quantity");
dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("TAXAMT");
dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("VALAMT");
```

to:

```
DataTable dtdatedisp = new DataTable();
dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("Order_Date", typeof(DateTime));
dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("Item_Quantity", typeof(int));
dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("TAXAMT", typeof(decimal));
dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("VALAMT", typeof(decimal));
```

... and it should start working.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd.aspx) you can read more about adding columns to a DataTable

Comment: If i'm doing this the date time is becoming a problem. there shold be an alternative to this

Comment: The DateTime is becoming a problem how?

Comment: since i'm converting the datetime into string previously, it says the datetime can not be converted from string. if i did not convet the datetime into string, the datetime is displaying in wrong format

Comment: I've gven yours as a right answer as i got a near solution from you and i modified it for my project. Thanks

Comment: I see - I did not notice you were converting the date to string. The test app I wrote to reproduce this problem did not do that. I would argue that if you can avoid converting dates to strings, you should avoid it. Generally stronger types should be ToString()-ed only for display purposes, last second before displaying them.